# How do I disable ajax on file fields?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm having some problems where using `drupal_get_form()` breaks the upload/remove functionality of a file field when it's processed with ajax. It seems this may be a core issue (http://drupal.org/node/1526300) but I haven't found a solution that works for me yet.

I've noticed that the form degrades gracefully when ajax is disabled in the browser and the file field works correctly.

I would like to just disable ajax for this form but I don't see how. I don't see any `#ajax` elements in `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_field_widget_form_alter()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can force the buttons to submit normally by unbinding the javascript events using something like this in a form alter:

```
// Disable ajax upload for file field
drupal_add_js("jQuery(function() { jQuery('#edit-field-image :submit').unbind(); });", 'inline');
```

It would be nice if there was a way to not have the javascript bound in the first place by manipulating the `$form` (or something else).

Comment: Excellent workaround, allowing to solve temporarily some broken AJAX stuff. Saved my day. Would upvote five times if possible.

Comment: Awesome. It helped me solve the error "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator." while I was using Translated Entity Reference module. Thanks!