# Max File Upload Size set to big, but Ajax Error with old file size

Tags: ajax, files

I have changed the upload_max_filesize and the max body size in my `php.ini` to 15 MB. It used to be 2 MB. Drupal displays the max file size correctly, but when I try to upload files bigger than 2 MB - the old limit - I get an Ajax Error, telling me the entity is too large. Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: Have you changed the same on your web server?

Comment: Ah, it might also need a change in my Apache? This is a good hint. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server config. Do you happen to know how I can check it in PHP?

Comment: Yeah but only maybe :) Have you set all possible vars in php.ini? You can have: `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, and `suhosin.post.max_value_length` (if that's active). I believe both of the first two need to be set for things to take effect

Comment: They are both set to 15 MB.

Comment: It could well need changing at web server level then, might be an idea to get in touch with your sysadmin and ask how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

Just for documentation I'd like to add my findings here. I had this issue in Drupal 8, but I guess the Drupal version can be neglected to answer this question.

---

#### Suhosin

As @Clive already mentioned it in the comments to the question it's definitely worth a look under `/admin/reports/status/php` if the Suhosin PHP extension is enabled.

In https://www.drupal.org/node/725056 people suggest to disable this extension completely, but it's maybe better as @Clive suggested to simply override one of its parameters by editing your `php.ini`. Or by setting this in `settings.php` – if that is possible at all – via `ini_set('suhosin.post.max_value_length', '-1');` or something like that. Maybe it's a different parameter you have to override.

---

#### Or Apache

If there's no Suhosin extension enabled, you may find this forum post valuable: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-04-07/ajax-error-when-uploading-large-files where it's suggested to disable or reconfigure Apache's `mod_security` security mod.

---

#### Or JS

Last but not least you could simply try to circumvent Ajax completely by unbinding the event handler for the submit button, or by removing it completely.

**Drupal 7**

```
// Disable ajax upload for file field
drupal_add_js("jQuery(function() { jQuery('#edit-field-image :submit').unbind(); });", 'inline');
```

Source: [How do I disable ajax on file fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/how-do-i-disable-ajax-on-file-fields)

**Drupal 8**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.autokill = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // $('.form-managed-file > input.form-submit').remove();
      $submit_button = $('.form-managed-file > input.form-submit');
      $submit_button.unbind();
      $submit_button.removeClass('js-hide');
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```