# I cannot upload an image - 404 ajax error

Tags: 8, ajax

When I try to upload an image, image is not generating and I always get ajax error.

I cannot upload an image.

I get a 404 ajax error.

[image]

I use Drupal 8.54

php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 254M 
upload_max_filesize = 20M 
post_max_size = 20M 
max_execution_time = 90
```

No error - Recent log messages.

The files directory ( sites/default/files ) permissions - 777

I don't find any solution or references about that.

Edit:

I can't upload file.

When I want to upload more than 8KB files, get ajax error.

Comment: Stock 8.54 image uploads work fine. Without telling us what custom & contrib modules you have installed, or what could be the *likely* cause of it, this question will probably end up getting closed as "Unclear what you're asking" or "Too broad".

Comment: Generally image uploads work fine but  in my case not.

It is core image field ( field_image)

Comment: Any errors in the Watchdog (db logging) log?  Also, what do your system error logs say? E.g. the PhP error log or web server error log.

Comment: There is no error - db logging, server error log file...

I made a short video

https://youtu.be/PQcwu_tTj3s

Comment: Possibly related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/144323/15055

Answer (score 0):

This part of the AJAX error message can be helpful for you:

> the requested url /@custom was not found on this server

This may have the following root causes (including but not limited to):

- .htaccess settings
- Your settings.php

Comment: It happens when I try to upload an image more than 8-10 KB. I think - server side issues, not drupal cms issue.

Comment: This means: you have tested with the same image file on localhost and it worked fine?

Comment: No, a remote server, I can upload an image 5KB but more than that - the AJAX error message.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer with this information